# why the validation can't be required

Tags: jquery, validation, gulp

I use `glup` and the plugin 'laravel-elixir' to pack js.
my gulpfile.js code is :

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('app.js');
    mix.browserify('libs/jquery-validate.js','./public/js/libs/jquery-validate.js');
});
```

app.js code is:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
// require('jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js');
$(document).ready(function () {
});
```

jquery-validation.js code is:

```
require('jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js');
$("#form").validate({
  rules: {
     name: "required",
  },
  messages: {
     name: "name can't null",
  }
});
```

at the end of body ,i use this two js like this:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/libs/jquery-validation.js"></script>
```

but when the `require('jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js')`in app.js, jquery-validation can work,but if it in jquery-validation.js, the consle will throw error :

```
jquery-validate.js:11842 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function
    at Object.3.jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js (jquery-validate.js:11842)
    at s (jquery-validate.js:1)
    at e (jquery-validate.js:1)
    at jquery-validate.js:1
```

why the `require('jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js')` can't in jquery.validate.js